# Delete directory which needs admin perms with c++

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I'm trying to delete Windows Defender's scans history and backup history using C++, but I have no clue how I can do it.

I'm using this code:

```cpp
std::string wdefenderhistory = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\History"; //defender history
std::string wdefenderbackupstore = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\BackupStore"; //defender backups

if (std::filesystem::exists(wdefenderhistory)) {
    std::filesystem::remove_all(wdefenderhistory);
}
        
if (std::filesystem::exists(wdefenderbackupstore)) {
    std::filesystem::remove_all(wdefenderbackupstore);
}
```

I tried already with `std::fs::remove()` and `std::remove()`, but nothing works.

Any way to force deleting a folder with admin rights without using `system()` / `ShellExecute()` syntax?

Started the program as admin, etc etc - nothing works, so I'm asking there.

`std::fs::remove_all()` is also giving me a memory error:

[image]

I'm sure for 99% that error code will be 0x5

Comment: By design, this should be impossible without getting the right permissions.

Comment: how do i get it? i mean w/ code not manually ;p

Comment: Code is not a way to get around access rights. If the file and directory permissions don't give the right to delete something manually, then using code is not going to change that.

Comment: [`std::fs::remove_all()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) is not giving you a memory error.  It is simply throwing a `filesystem_error` exception that you are not catching: "*The overload that does not take a `std::error_code&` parameter throws `filesystem::filesystem_error` on underlying OS API errors*" The exception contains details about why `remove_all()` failed (probably "access denied" in your case), so you should catch it and display its details.  Or, you can provide a `std::error_code` variable to `remove_all()` to fill in on failure, then it won't `throw` anymore.

Comment: "*Started the program as admin*" - but, is it running as an **elevated** admin? Just running as an ordinary admin doesn't guarantee you actually have sufficient rights to access the `Scans` folder. Are you running your program with the `Run as administrator` option, or have added a `requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator` UAC manifest to your program? Does the user you are choosing to run the program with actually have delete rights to the `Scans` folder? You can't *force* your code to gain rights, you can only do what the process's assigned user has permissions to do.

Comment: Defender is extra special and might prevent your attack with its kernel driver...

Comment: @Anders but here i want to delete history of all defends, im not toggling it off ;)

Comment: also @RemyLebeau, how i can modify ACLs of the folder? ;p
std::filesystem::perms is not enough or im doing something wrong with it?

Comment: @mcs if you don't have permissions to access/delete the folder, you certainly don't have permission to alter its security. An admin with sufficient rights will have to alter the security outside of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some folders in directory (only CacheManager and everything under it needs) does not needs the "admin" perms,

so i solved the problem with:

code is deleting every folder w/o admin privilege and keeps C:\..\History path :)

```cpp
    std::string wdefenderhistory = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\History"; //defender history
    std::string wdefenderbackupstore = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\BackupStore"; //defender backups

    if (std::filesystem::exists(wdefenderhistory)) {
        const std::filesystem::path defenderhist{ "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\History" };
        for (auto const& dir_entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{ defenderhist })
        {
            try {
                const std::filesystem::path cachemanager{ "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\Scans\\History\\CacheManager" };
                for (auto const& dir_entryy : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{ cachemanager })
                {
                    if (dir_entry != dir_entryy && dir_entry != cachemanager) {
                        std::filesystem::remove_all(dir_entry);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& ex) {
                std::cout
                    << "what():  " << ex.what() << '\n'
                    << "path1(): " << ex.path1() << '\n'
                    << "path2(): " << ex.path2() << '\n'
                    << "code().value():    " << ex.code().value() << '\n'
                    << "code().message():  " << ex.code().message() << '\n'
                    << "code().category(): " << ex.code().category().name() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
```

Please mark this thread as solved because i dont know how to do it, thank you